# umbraco 7 how to access database MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-connection, umbraco, dbcontext

I have Umbraco 7 website with MVC.

I want to perform some custom action on the database.

As I understand I should be using DbContext to connect.

I have referenced System.Data.Entity to get to DbContext class. However when I'm trying to use DbContext I'm getting an error saying

```
The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing
a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

In my models namespace:

```
public class umbracoDbDSN : DbContext
{
    //some code
}
```

Can you let me know what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are mixing things up.  Umbraco uses PetaPoco as ORM, not entity framework.  You don't need to include the System.Data.Entity.  Neither you need the DbContext.
However, if you have existing DataLayer logic which you need to incorporate, for legacy systems, you might need to continue with your code above.  Then look for entity framework tutorials on the internet to continue your journey.

If you are not dragging legacy stuff, then the question is: do you want to perform queries on custom tables or do you want to query the Umbraco tables for some reason.

Let's start with the last one.  Querying the umbraco tables:
If you want to connect to the umbraco SQL tables, I start wondering why.  There is a ContentCache, which is blasting fast, and it enables you to query very quickly everything you need from the content section.  You have API's for relationships, media, users, members and everything you need.  So the question remains, WHY would you ever connect to the umbraco tables.

However, if you want to store data in custom tables, I would read this article of Warren: http://creativewebspecialist.co.uk/2013/07/16/umbraco-petapoco-to-store-blog-comments/

The idea is simple, you reuse the existing code base to extend umbraco behaviour without storing stuff in the content section.

Below a simple example for reusing the databaseconnection while querying some proper created table...

```
var db = ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.Database;
// Fetch a collection of contacts from the db.
var listOfContacs = db.Fetch<Contact>(new Sql().Select("*").From("myContactsTable"));
```

Comment: Thanks @dampee I ound today the petapoco blog article so got it working now. I got another issue - I'm not getting any error message but despite I did like in petapoco the row is not inserted in my db table :(

Comment: If you can't solve the problem, don't hesitate to contact ask a new question on SO or on the umbraco forum (http://our.umbraco.org).

Comment: Thanks @dampee, I did ask, didn't get any resonse for now. I'm wondering if the problem is with the connection. I installed u7 into existing database and the db conn str is different than classic one eg. db server, usr pwd etc. I was wondering should I s5till use classic con str to connect to the database cos the current u7 string (which use Umbraco.sdf) is not working?

Comment: tweet your post on our with hashtag umbraco.  Someone will come up.  I am not sure about your question.  If i understand you well, you should come up with a way you want to work, after that you need to make it work.  Which fase are you doing nog?